# MATLAB - Why doesn't HP+LP=NOTCH?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I'm having a conceptual issue with notch filters.  As far as I understand it, a notch filter output is equal to the sum of highpass and lowpass filter outputs.  However, a quick test in MATLAB doesn't show this.  Here's some testing code:

```
% Load a simple signal and specify constants
load handel; % this loads the signal, y, and its sampling rate, Fs
nData=y;
nFreq=[55 65];
nOrder=4;

% Create a lowpassed signal
[b a]=butter(nOrder,nFreq(1)/(Fs/2),'low');
nLP_Data=filter(b,a,nData);

% Create a highpassed signal
[b a]=butter(nOrder,nFreq(2)/(Fs/2),'high');
nHP_Data=filter(b,a,nData);

% Combine LP and HP signals
nCombinedHPLP=nLP_Data+nHP_Data;

% Create a notch filtered signal
[b a]=butter(nOrder/2,nFreq/(Fs/2),'stop'); % The notch filter uses twice the first input argument for its order, hence the "/2"
nN_Data=filter(b,a,nData);

% Plot each and output the total difference in the signals to the Command Window
plot(nN_Data,'r')
hold all
plot(nCombinedHPLP,'b')
legend({'Notched signal','Combined HP, LP signals'});
sum(abs(nCombinedHPLP-nN_Data))
```

I'm thinking that the difference is due to phase effects of the filters, as changing `filter` to `filtfilt` yields two identical signals.  Is there not a way (using `filter') of recreating the effect of a notch filter with a highpass and lowpass filter?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why don't you apply the filters in series instead?

Comment: Better place to ask: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I believe that would yield a bandpass-type response.  (If I lowpassed the signal at 55 Hz, then there wouldn't be much left above that frequency; if I were to then highpass the remaining signal at 65 Hz, there would be very little left!)

Comment: interesting observation is that 3 people made the exact same mistake of saying that band notch filter = low pass * high pass (series cascade).  **this is not true**.  stop copying each other's answer.  you're not adding anything new, and especially stop copying if it's wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rogare,

You HAVE created a notch filter; you just created one with different phase than what a single butter filter would do, as you suspected.

Both your BUTTER filters will have their own phase responses, and there's no guarantee that the processing of your data with both of those filters will have the same net phase as processing your data ONCE with a hand-made band-pass filter.    There's no rule that says butter will spend time and energy trying to get the phase of a low-pass and a high-pass filter to behave like the phase of a band-pass filter (in fact, it would be weird if it did!)

However, the MAGNITUDE of the FFT of the resulting data agrees quite nicely:

```
subplot(2,1,1); 
plot(abs(fftshift(fft(nCombinedHPLP)))); 
title('My Notch')
subplot(2,1,2); 
plot(abs(fftshift(fft(nN_Data)))); 
title('Real Notch')
```

Comment: remark also that the filters do not cut off exactly at the specific cut off frequency.  this is a design consideration that you have to take care of when designing your filter.  in the particular case that is used here, the lp and hp filters overlap a lot due to the fact that the drop off isn't so fast.  for this reason, it looks like you haven't done any filtering because the notch doesn't completely notch out the signal.  it simply attenuates the signal a little bit between 55 and 65.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a conceptual problem: in the opening paragraph of your question you say

> As far as I understand it, a notch filter output is equal to the sum
>   of highpass and lowpass filter outputs

If that were the case, then any signal that passes either the lowpass or the highpass will get through (at low frequency, the lowpass lets it through, so the sum of the outputs of  lowpass + highpass lets low frequencies through. Ditto for high frequencies, if you swap the words "low" and "high"...).

There's a difference between applying *in series* vs *summing outputs*. I think that is where your confusion is coming from. And yes - depending on how a filter is constructed, how steep it is, etc, you will get all kinds of effects when you apply them in series...

Comment: I thought this too, at first, but note, he's talking about a notched band-STOP filter; not a band-pass filter.  So if FILT1 retains everything below f1, and FILT2 retains everything above f2, FILT1(y(t)) + FILT2(y(t)) has all the right parts retained as long as f1 < f2.  The opposite (for a band-pass filter), is, as you've noticed, not true.

Comment: @Pete - I should learn to read the question... thanks for putting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

As the order of the notch filter is twice of the order of LP or HP filters, that should indicate that a NF can also be derived as conv(LP,HP).

The concept that you asking is that of superposition, which would presuppose equal length filters.

Comment: 1.  **which would presuppose equal length filters** is not true.  LP and HP don't have to be equal length for you to be able to do (LP*x)+(HP*y) (the pieces may need to be padded with 0 depending on how far * extends) and in fact, even if you want to simplify into (CP)*x where CP=LP+HP, you can always pad the shorter one with 0 to match.  2.  **that should indicate that a NF can also be derived as conv(LP,HP)**.  if LP and HP do not overlap in frequency space, what happens when you do conv(LP,HP)?  then think about your statement.  is it true?